# COUNTIF cell contains one of these strings

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to have a cell state whether it contains one of many strings.

```
=COUNTIF(A1,"Not found")
```

The cells I'm checking have multiple variants of the word *"Not found"* and be case insensitive.

I'd like to have either a column or a cell where I can state multiple strings that will trigger the COUNTIF, eg:

```
Not found
None Available
NA
```

So far the COUNTIF or IF statements I've tried only allow for one string to be checked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you have the strings that need to be counted in B1:B3 and the range you want to check is column A, try

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(--regexmatch(A1:A, JOIN("|",B1:B3))))
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks! That's worked. Is there a case insensitive way of doing this?

Comment: There is:  =sum(ArrayFormula(--regexmatch(A1:A, "(?i)"&JOIN("|",B1:B3))))

Comment: Is there any way to exclude blank cells from the criterion range? I want to allow others to make a copy of my spreadsheet, and fill in the values that they want to match. I don't know how many values they will enter, so I am planning to set my criterion range to an entire column (e.g. A1:A).

Comment: Yes, use textjoin(): =sum(ArrayFormula(--regexmatch(A1:A, "(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B1:B))))

Answer (score 0):

You better use COUNTIFS and then with a wildcard. If "not" is the word what is in every cell, you can use a wildcard like:

```
=countifs(A1:D1;"*not*")
```